# Get type of an assembly loaded in a new AppDomain

Tags: c#, reflection, appdomain

I'm using [this method to create the object I want to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms224132.aspx).

The constructor of the object is successfully called.

Now, I want to call a method via reflection, but as I found out, I need to know the type. And when I do something like

```
Type type = Type.GetType(this.typeName);
```

`type` is null.

So, what I need to know is: How do I get the type of an assembly loaded in a new AppDomain?

Comment: Type.GetType() requires a fully qualified type name, one that contains the assembly name as well as the type name.  You probably want to use Assembly.GetType() instead, it isn't quite clear from the question.

Comment: That's right, but, i don't have an `Assembly` object. nowhere :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.type type object is an object by itself and has a type object pointer member in it, and it’s member refers to itself because the System.Type type object is itself an “instance” of a type object. And System.Object’s GetType method returns the address stored in the specified object’s type object pointer member. In other words the GetType method returns a pointer to an object’s type object, and this is how you can determine the true type of any object in the system.

Use System.Reflection.AssemblyName is an utility class which gives you complete details of an assembly's unique identity in full. Use GetType method of this Class to know the type of the Assembly loaded.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

Comment: But this examples only shows me how to receive the type, if the existing class is in my enviroment, but it isn't ):

Comment: In that case you need to load the assembly by referencing it in the Appdomain. Load the assembly and extract the manifest. The manifest maintains an interrnal structure of all the classes inside the assembly. So by reading this internal structure of the assembly in the manifest file you would come to know the interface, class and types supported by the assembly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the full assembly qualified name, so you can recreate it with `Type.GetType()`

```
this.typeName = typeof(MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Without this, the executing assembly will be searched for the type which doesn't always contain your type.

Comment: I understood, but my "MyClass" is in another project, and therefore it cannot be found that way.

Comment: If the assembly is loaded, itsn't full name can be retrieved, I just don't know the way you are trying to get your `this.typeName` field. Can you post more code?

Comment: Line 61: You can just use `Type type = this.o.GetType();`

Comment: i tried to, but this gives me "System.MarshalByRefObject" and not the one i need to know.

Comment: What is the value of `this.typename`? Is Type.Name or Type.FullName? Example: `System.String` or `String`? If it's the full name, then you can construct the full qualified name with `Type type = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", this.typeName, this.assemblyName));`

Comment: this.typename is "Evil.MyCode" and this.assemblyname is "MyCode". i tried to do what you said, but still not working (NullPointerException). btw, does this exception means that the type was not found? and if so, why doesn't "GetType" simply throws an Exception?

Comment: Good question, `GetType` should just throw exception instead return null. It seems like the type is not accessible or the assembly is not loaded. Doing is manually, `Type.GetType("Evil.MyCode, MyCode")` should return a non-null type.

Comment: Still null, mh, perhaps this "Activator" doesn't load the assembly where we can find it :D is there a way to list all assemblys in an AppDomain?

Comment: Yes, this funktion does exist, but throws a very strange exception http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/getassemblies.png/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved the problem:
I created an interface, and used typeof(MyInterface) to work arround.

I hope this could help you.